# Github Pages removes custom url on deploy

Tags: github, dns, github-pages

I have a GitHub Pages site set up with a custom domain. Whenever I commit and deploy to the site, I lose the custom domain and have to go into the repo settings and re-add.

Anyone know why Github does this and how to make it stop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you are using a custom domain, check that you have the `CNAME` file with your domain name on the root of the repo. (The CNAME filename must be uppercase)

From the [docs](https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-custom-domains/#github-repository-setup-errors):

> Custom domains are stored in a CNAME file in the root of your repository. You can add or update your custom domain through your repository settings.

check the GitHub [Troubleshooting custom domains](https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-custom-domains/#the-cname-file-isnt-properly-formatted)

Comment: you know, i did not include that extremely pertinent part of the info. turned out the dns value for the CNAME had not trickled down to github yet, despite the site working correctly and `dig` showing the correct resolutions. ;_; impatience is always what kills me with DNS resolution.